# Unable to remove the elements still the array get cleared

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am fetching the data from the server each 10 sec, in this, i am getting 3 type of the data,

After the timeout call, i am removing the existing data, i can witness the console show that the array clears, but the elements still keep append upon.

how can i clear both elements in the DOM and unbind as well..

my close function is keep called, but the elements not remove from DOM.

my single view :

```
singleton.view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName     :'article',
    template0   : function(value){
                    var label = value === 0 ? "projectName" : value === 1  ? "assignedTo" :"projectName";
                    return _.template("<a href='#'><%= "+label+" %></a>");
                },
    template1   : _.template($('#boardTemplate').html()),
    initialize  :function(prams){
        this.template = this['template'+0](prams.subTempNo);
    },
    close:function(){
        console.log('clean up') // i am getting consoled
        this.unbind();// i am unbinding
        this.remove();// i am removing
    },
    render:function(){
        var temp = this.template;
        this.$el.html(temp(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
}); 
return singleton.view;
```

in the views :

```
listViewAppender:function(item,i){
            var listElement = new singleton.view({model:item,tempNo:0,subTempNo:i,tagName:'li'});
            listElement.close(); // whenever i call the new instance i am removing old stuff..
            this.$el.find('.'+this.classItems[i]).append(listElement.render().el);
        },
```

How can i fix this issue.. any correct approach pelase..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gone through across my functions, i find the issue in the line of `this.listCatch[i] = listElement;` wrongly declared.

Later i declared the array by manually, it's works fine. in my initialize i introduced 3 arrays, what i required now it works fine.

```
this.listCatch = [];


            for(var i=0;i<this.listItems.length; i+=1){
                this.listCatch[i] = [];
            }
```

So  before pushing the model to array,  now the array introduced solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just a quick rework.....you're going to have to test it out. Comment with what happens and I'll correct the code below.

Can you try

```
listViewSet:function(key,i){
    var l = this.listCatch.length;
    if(l > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            console.log(this.listCatch[i]);
            this.listCatch[i].remove();
         }
    }

    this.listCatch = [];

    _.each(this.listCollection.models, function(model){
        that.listViewAppender(model,i); //setting agian.
    });
},

listViewAppender:function(item,i){
    var listElement = new singleton.view({model:item,tempNo:0,subTempNo:i,tagName:'li'});
    console.log(listElement);
    this.$el.find('.'+this.classItems[i]).append(listElement.render().el);
    this.listCatch[i] = listElement;
},
```

Comment: sure, let me try this way.

Comment: i am getting this error : TypeError: this.listCatch[i].remove is not a function

Comment: edited the code a bit. I'm assuming that list View Appender is called before listViewSet otherwise there'd be nothing to clear. If listViewSet is called first just wrap the for loop in an if statement that checks that 'l' (array length) is greater than 0. Also I added two console log to check that this.listCatch[i] is always an instance of a Backbone View

Comment: ok, but the last line, without creating a array how you assigning the listElement..

Comment: this.listCatch is already an empty array from listViewSet. Line 8 in the code above. Ideally its initialization is moved to an initializer. So then, in the last line, listElement can be added to the array. (note that there is a missing semicolon on the last line I will fix it now.).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24119/discussion-between-thearchitect-and-3gwebtrain)